# How to animate image to top right of screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am new in android development.
I want to get my image from Center to the top right of the screen while changing the size of the image (Smaller).

I tried the following things -

1. Hard coding the translationX & translationY, Entering a specific value like -150dp which would look good in my Emulator screen but the image position is different on various devices.
2. .getX . getY methods, I tried to place an invisible image (alpha 0) where i want to place the image and getx & y of the image and setting the translationx,y but it don't work, The image swipes off my screen.

I think if i could get the position of an object like textview and setting the image position to the **objectposition+somevalue** would work **but i don't know how to do it.** Anyone can help me with it?

Here is the image, of what I am trying to do.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this code may helpful

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_off" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
  view.animate().x(dx).y(-dy)
```

In the documentation it is written that these are absolute coordinates, but in practice it turned out to be a delta, which I need to change. X - calculate by left side, Y - top.

For take coordinate you can use rect:

```
 private fun getLocationOnScreen(view: View): Rect {
    val rect = Rect()
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)
    return rect
}
```

Also you need to change the size image. For them use scale animation, but before need calculate percents. Some like this:

```
val textRect = getLocationOnScreen(textView)
val imageRect = getLocationOnScreen(imageView)
val width = getWidth()//some method that get screen width on pxl
val height = getHeight()
val xScale = (width - textRect.right) / (imageRect.right - imageRect.left).toFlooat()
val yScale = (height - textRect.bottom) / (imageRect.bottom - imageRect.top).toFloat()
val scale = ScaleAnimation(
            1.0f, xScale ,
            1.0f, yScale ,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivotX, // optional
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivotY //optional
)
scale.duration = 1000L
imageView.startAnimation(scale)
```

I hope something will help, or maybe nothing it doesn't work =)